# how to display data dynamically on html page via jsp session

Tags: java, jsp, session, jakarta-ee

I have text area that is in bullet format and i want to display that data in html in bullet format via session.

so how to send that data ?? every user data contain and length is different for example ( 1 user use 3 bullets points ans 2 user use 5 bullet points ) how to send that dynamic data on html page and Display. DATABASE IS NOT USED ..

Comment: That's not much info and not much code you've tried. Maybe `<c:forEach` is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Identify and parse bullet points from each text area(lets say post)

```
class BulletPoint{
  String content;
  public BulletPoint(String content){
        super();
        this.content=content;
     }
   //put public getters and setters here
}

class Post{
 List<BulletPoint> bulletPoints=new ArrayList<>();
 //put public getters and setters here
}

@WebServlet("/posts")
class DisplayPostServlet extends HttpServlet {

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response)
        throws IOException {
    //parse and prepare text area contents to list
    //for each text area 
       //new Post p
        //create bulletin list for post
        //set bulletins to post
    //end for 

    //simple example 
    List<Post> posts=new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
      Post newPost=new Post();
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
          Bulletin bulletin=new Bulletin("bulletin content"+j);
          newPost.getBulletins().add(bulletin);
        }

       posts.add(newPost);
    }


   //add posts in request scope, and forward to jsp page
   request.setAttribute("posts",posts);
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/displayPosts.jsp").forward(request,                response);
  }


}
```

### displayPosts.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<html>
 <head>

     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>


  <div>
     <c:forEach var="singlePost"  items="${posts}" varStatus="loopIndex">
      <ul> Post ${loopIndex}
        <c:forEach var="singleBulletin"  items="${singlePost.bulletins}">
            <li><c:out value="${singleBulletin.content}"/>
            </li>
         </c:forEach>
      </ul>
    </c:forEach>
 </div>



</body>

</html>
```